# Looking for Facebook credits callback page example

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Can some one tell me where can I find a Facebook Credits callback example in asp.net ?
thx

Answer (score 1):

There is a great blog about how to implement the complete credits API flow via asp.net at http://www.m-webs.com/blog_facebookcredits.html